# Why doesn't SQL Server use port 1521

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Oracle uses port 1521. SQL Server uses port 1433. Why doesn't SQL Server also just use port 1521?

Specifically, I'm asking why SQL Server defaults to port 1433 and not another port.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes no sense. Port assignment is arbitrary and simply a convention. If you have multiple sql server instances they will be on different ports, not just 1433

Comment: Right but I just wanted to know why SQL defaults to port 1433.  My mistake for not being specific enough.

Comment: The answer is going to be "because Microsoft chose it". There's no standard port for SQL. MySQL uses yet another port number by default. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: Each product has its own port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it the wrong way round.

1433 is the registered port for SQL Server.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt

The question should be, why does Oracle habitually use 1521

Mostly using standard ports makes it easier to configure firewalls.